# Regex - Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to create a PCRE regex to match every file in a list except one. Doing this exclusion programmatically would be a joke, of course, but I have to do it using regex since I have no choice. This is what I created so far:

```
^(?!transport).*\.php$
```

Basically, I need to match every file with php extension extept `transport.php`. So here are the result of my tests:

```
transport.php           # Not Matched! Good!
test_transport.php      # Matched! Good!
transport_test.php      # Not Matched! Bad!
test_transport_test.php # Matched! Good!
```

Well the problem is that my regex is not matching files like `transport(.*)\.php` (that start with `transport` but also contain other characters before the extension) and this is not ok for me. But I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestion?

Comment: You just need to confirm the literal `.` is not matched after transport in the lookahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this negative lookahead:

```
^(?!transport\.php$).*\.php$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tA9eY6/1)

`(?!transport)` on the other hand will fail the match for any file starting with `transport`